# Broserify exported function error: is not a function

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have a module "./lib/common.js", like this:

```
function foo(text){
  console.log(text);
}

function boo(text){
  console.log(text);
}

module.exports=foo;
module.exports=boo;
```

I'm trying to include these functions in another js file using browserify :

```
var common =require('./lib/common.js');
$(document).ready(function() {
  common.foo('hi');
});
```

Browserify creates the bundle,but on the browser I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: common.foo is not a function
```

Comment: I think you have to do `module.exports = { foo: foo, boo: boo };` ES6 offers an alternate syntax

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was very stupid, I was overwriting my module.exports with the last row module.exports=boo;

With this change it works:

```
module.export.foo=foo;
module.export.boo=boo;
```